# Construct co-occurrence matrix from a list of list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have n lists consisting of some values.

```
['a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'd', 'e']
['b', 'e']
```

Here n = 4.

This should yield a dataframe like the below one

```
      'a'  'b'  'c'  'd'  'e'
'a'    0    1    0    1    1
'b'    1    0    1    1    2
'c'    0    1    0    1    1
'd'    1    1    1    0    2
'e'    1    2    1    2    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
l1=['a', 'b']
l2=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l3=['a', 'd', 'e']
l4=['b', 'e']
```

Get a nested list from the lists:

```
l = [i for i in [l1,l2,l3,l4]]
```

Get all the combinations within each list using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
c = [list(itertools.combinations(i,2)) for i in l]
#[[('a', 'b')],
#[('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('d', 'e')],
#[('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('d', 'e')],
#[('b', 'e')]]
```

Flatten the nested lists. Note that each element is added in original and reversed order using `chain.from_iterable((i, i[::-1])`.

```
a = list(chain.from_iterable((i, i[::-1]) for c_ in c for i in c_))
```

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and aggregate by `size` to generate a cooccurrence matrix from the result

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
pd.pivot_table(df, index=0, columns=1, aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

1    a    b    c    d    e
0                         
a  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
b  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
c  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
d  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  2.0
e  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 10):

```
lst = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['a', 'd'],
    ['b', 'e']
]
```

You can use `get_dummies` + `groupby` and `sum`, followed by a `dot` product:

```
u = (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(lst), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
       .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
       .sum())

v = u.T.dot(u)
v.values[(np.r_[:len(v)], ) * 2] = 0

print(v)
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  0  1  0
b  1  0  1  1  2
c  0  1  0  1  1
d  1  1  1  0  1
e  0  2  1  1  0
```

---

**Details**
First, load your dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(lst)

   0  1     2     3
0  a  b  None  None
1  b  c     d     e
2  a  d  None  None
3  b  e  None  None
```

Next, generate one-hot-encodings for these values. This is the first step to computing the co-occurrence counts.

```
pd.get_dummies(_, prefix='', prefix_sep='')

   a  b  b  c  d  e  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Next, combine the columns by header and count them.

```
_.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  1  0
3  0  1  0  0  1

u = _
```

Next, compute the cross tabulation with a dot product.

```
u.T.dot(u)

   a  b  c  d  e
a  2  1  0  1  0
b  1  3  1  1  2
c  0  1  1  1  1
d  1  1  1  2  1
e  0  2  1  1  2

v = _
```

Finally, set the diagonal to 0.

```
v.values[(np.r_[:len(v)], ) * 2] = 0
v

   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  0  1  0
b  1  0  1  1  2
c  0  1  0  1  1
d  1  1  1  0  1
e  0  2  1  1  0
```